# ComponentScan ignores excludeFilters (in test)

Tags: java, spring, component-scan

I can't figure out, how to exclude a configuration (e.g. as  [described here](https://www.concretepage.com/spring/spring-component-scan-include-and-exclude-filter-example)) in a test. What I really want is to ignore a configuration in a @WebMvcTest, but even the following simpler example does not work for me:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ComponentScan(excludeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, classes = {
        ComponentScanTest.ExcludedConfig.class }))
class ComponentScanTest {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Test
    void testInclusion() throws Exception { // This test succeeds, no exception is thrown.
        applicationContext.getBean(IncludedBean.class); 
    }

    @Test
    void testExclusion() throws Exception { // This test fails, because ExcludedBean is found.
        assertThrows(NoSuchBeanDefinitionException.class, () -> applicationContext.getBean(ExcludedBean.class));
    }

    @Configuration
    static class IncludedConfig {
        @Bean
        public IncludedBean includedBean() {
            return new IncludedBean();
        }
    }

    static class IncludedBean { }

    @Configuration
    static class ExcludedConfig {
        @Bean
        public ExcludedBean excludedBean() {
            return new ExcludedBean();
        }
    }

    static class ExcludedBean { }
}
```

Why is the `ExcludedBean` found in `testExclusion()`?
How do I correctly exclude a configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above test class will pass with the @Profile annotation to control the bean creation.

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ComponentScan
@ActiveProfiles("web")
class ComponentScanTest {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Test
    void testInclusion() throws Exception { // This test succeeds, no exception is thrown.
        applicationContext.getBean(IncludedBean.class);
    }

    @Test
    void testExclusion() throws Exception { // This test fails, because ExcludedBean is found.
        assertThrows(NoSuchBeanDefinitionException.class, () -> applicationContext.getBean(ExcludedBean.class));
    }

    @Configuration
    @Profile("web")
    static class IncludedConfig {
        @Bean
        public IncludedBean includedBean() {
            return new IncludedBean();
        }
    }

    static class IncludedBean {
    }

    @Configuration
    @Profile("!web")
    static class ExcludedConfig {
        @Bean
        public ExcludedBean excludedBean() {
            return new ExcludedBean();
        }
    }

    static class ExcludedBean {
    }
}
```

**Update** : Following code works on `@ComponentScan`

Create a Configuration class and annotate with `@ComponentScan` as required

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(excludeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, classes = {
        ComponentScanTest.ExcludedConfig.class }))
public class TestConfiguration {

}
```

and provide the ApplicationContext for the test class as follows

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes= {TestConfiguration.class})
class ComponentScanTest {
  //.. Everything else remains the same.
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Creating a separate `TestConfiguration` will solve my issue.